# Prevent fork bomb inside docker container

Tags: ssh, pam, containers, docker

I am currently struggling with limiting number of processes for user which I called `sandbox`.

I configured processes limit inside `/etc/security/limits.conf` like this:

```
sandbox            hard    nproc            100
```

But if I want to connect to container as `sandbox` user, ssh returns:

```
shell request failed on channel 0
```

So I logged in as `root` and checked how many processes are running by `sandbox` user, but it's less than 5.

So what could be preventing me to login through ssh?
Without setting limits ssh login for `sandbox` user works ok.

Or is there any other way to prevent fork bomb attack?

Answer (score 2):

any error when connecting to an sshd is logged into /var/log/auth.log (in debian-based OS, or security in redhat-based systems)

If it's not, set `LogLevel VERBOSE` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and reload sshd. This will show you why sshd is refusing your connection next.

That said, back to your fork-bomb limiter: docker machines are based on LXC, a container system for Linux. LXC are using CGROUPS to manage resource limits for each container.

in /sys/fs/cgroups, you can setup any limit for a running LXC, and in /Var/lib/lxc/vmname/config, you can setup the limits that will be enforced at boottime.

Limiting the number of processes in a cgroup is done by the *task counter subsystem* (added in the Linux kernel in 2011 http://lkml.iu.edu//hypermail/linux/kernel/1109.0/01455.html )

With a recent enough linux kernel, limiting the number of allowed processes for a cgroup is therefore done by adding this kind of line into your lxc's config file :

```
lxc.cgroup.tasks.limit = 1024
```

for a maximum of 1024 processes

(disclaimer: information not checked on a real machine though, to be confirmed)

Comment: Thanks. For correction latest Docker containers are not based on LXC, LXC is available as driver. Docker containers native driver is based directly on kernel namespaces. But I really like idea with cgroups I did not know that it is possible limit process count. I am definitely going to try it.

Comment: As of today the task counter sub system has still not landed in the official kernel.